PyMUPDF - Converting from PDF to other Image format results in either very bad quality at the same file size or a very large file with similar quality
Let's say I have a PDF with 30 pages that is 2MB. If I use PyMUPDF and convert it to 30 PNGs or 30 JPGs (file format doesn't seem to matter) using get_pixmap on each page. The resulting image sizes when totaled will roughly equal the same size (about 2MB) but the image quality is terrible. Nearly illegible. If I start to up the dpi keyword argument to something in the range 200-300 DPI, the image quality starts to achieve parity, but now my files total over 20MB. Is there not a way to convert the PDF to images of comparable quality at similar size?
